# Eclipse and c++11

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I had programmed in c/c++ some years ago, amongst other languages, before I started to spend a lot of time on web stuff using php. Recently I decided to refresh my knowledge which is minimal in c++ using c++11. So, I went back to Eclipse, a few years old by now?

But obviously, my old version was not very well adaptable to C++11 because, even though I added the compiler directive "-std=c++11" in the appropriate places, the editor still complains, not only about current c++11 stuff, but also now about statements like "using namespace std" which used to be acceptable in the past. But the code compiles and runs just fine, but with a whole bunch of icons in the editor that just confuses any attempt to discover what actual errors exist.

So the c++11 stuff works, but the editor complains about stuff that (1) it did not complain about before and (2) refuses to accept with the more recent C++11 stuff. In fact, the bogus errors are so frequent that I have a devil of a time finding the real ones, a forest for the trees effect.

I have accessed whatever solutions have been offered for making the editor more tolerant, with no success. Any other thoughts out there? I am using Eclipse Juno under Window 7 with the cygwin compiler.

Comment: [Seen this?](http://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/User/FAQ#CDT_does_not_recognize_C.2B.2B11_features)

Comment: No joy BobbyDigital. Perhaps the difference between Indigo and Juno? Thanks for the reference though.